# ROS Timer: difference between types of NodeHandles?

Tags: ros, nodehandle, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

a student approached me a day back with a question that I just couldn't answer:
"Should a ROS timer be on a a private NodeHandle, or on a global one?" (or any other, obviously...)

We usually do something like the following:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_         = ros::NodeHandle(""); // for subscribers/publishers/...
ros::NodeHandle private_nh_ = ros::NodeHandle("~"); // for parameters
```

For parameters, subscribers etc. there is a clear difference which NodeHandle is used to access/initialize them.

Is there any for Timers?

Thank you for your insights!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233222/ros-timer:-difference-between-types-of-nodehandles?/) by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ROS timer does not have an associated ROS graph name, so the namespace of the nodehandle doesn't affect how the timer functions.

I believe (though I'm not entirely certain), that if your NodeHandles have different [callback queues](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning), then the timer callback will get called on queue of the associated NodeHandle. This is a fairly advanced use case and it requires explicit setup, so it's probably not something that most students will encounter.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-09**:
@ahendrix thanks. This sounds reasonable. And this is actually something nobody could answer here. :-)